# Why does my Photoshop CS5 always stuck when I use tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Before this, I'm just editing my photos like usual.  But when I'm too long using it, and after I open and close it for many times, it becomes slower.  Even if when I want to open the saved editing, or using tools, it takes too long to apply the changes that I want to make.  Sometimes, it stuck.  It really slow down my works.  Is it already cracks?  Help me!  :(

Answer (score 0):

It may not be fully closing down when you close it, try to look in the task manager and kill applications. Sounds like you are either running out of RAM or hitting a disk IO issue.

What are the specs of your machine, and what version of Windows are you using? Short answer is probably to upgrade your PC.

Comment: I'm using Asus i5, Windows 7 Ultimate with 8GB RAM..  Now I'm just using 2.98 GB..  I already look at the task manager.  So far I see there is nothing wrong there.  Hmmm  :(

Comment: Try an SSD hard disk.